# what changes are needed in react lifecycle methods when upgrading react from 16.9.0 to 16.14.0?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, upgrade, react-dom

I want to upgrade react from 16.9.0 to 16.14.0, I want to know what peer dependencies I should upgrade first, and what needs to be done to react lifecycle methods.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it without any major changes in our application since its not a major upgrade.